# Обьясните почему передаются аргументы char*& а char* не работает

Tags: c++

Читая чужой код встретил что-то вроде подобного кода

```
void func(char*& p1)
{
    p1 = (char*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(),HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,MAX_PATH);
    lstrcatA("RandomText");

}

int main()
{
    char* p1;
    func(p1);
    std::cout << p1 << std::endl;
}
```

Код в функции `func` мне кажеться удобным но я не совсем понимаю как он работает почему просто передача `char* p1` не работает и необходимо именно `char*& p1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь ровно та же ситуация, что и в коде

```
void func(int a) { a = 10;}
```

Вас же не удивляет, что при использовании такого кода

```
int x = 4;
func(x);
assert(x == 4);
```

все работает и переменная не изменяется?

А если просто добавить амперсанд, то сразу переменная будет изменена.

В приведенном коде такая же ситуация. Передавая переменную, Вы можете менять то, на что она указывает, но не само значение переменной. А как только появляется амперсанд, то в функцию передается не копия, а, грубо говоря, сама переменная и ее значение можно поменять.

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в том, что в с++ есть ссылки *(ака разыменованный указатель)*, который отличается от указателя на указатель только тем, что он не может быть пустым ***(иметь значение `NULL`, `nullptr`)***.

Это в какой-то мере позволяет обезопасить код таким образом, что вызываемый код, не должен обязятельно проверять на валидность переданного значения, т.к. без этого значения ваш код просто не соберется.

Вот пример того как это делается в двух случаях:

```
/* safe / ref */
void a(char *&value) {
    value = ...;
}

/* unsafe / pointer to pointer (to pointer... etc) */
void b(char **pp_value) {   /* Здесь нужна проверка! А вдруг передали NULL? */
    if (NULL == pp_value) { /* или assert... */
        return;
    }

    (*pp_value) = ...;      /* Работаем! */
}
```

Отличия вызова:

```
int main(void) {
    char *p_value = NULL;
    
    a(p_value);              /* ref to p_value *(char **)     */
    printf("%s\n", p_value); /* ну или ::std::cout << ...     */

    b(&p_value);             /* pointer to pointer p_value    */
    printf("%s\n", p_value); /* ну или ::std::cout << ...     */
}
```